# Can you go against the Reader-Response?

Tags: creative-writing

So, as I'm writing, I noticed something I've been subconsciously doing for a while:

> "Oh, you're concerned about something, guess this is a red-letter day" Iris smirked at Two, well as much as a hooked beak allowed her to. Iris was one of the genetically engineered troops at the Foundation's disposal, basically a humanoid avian.
>
> Her irises were bright yellow. Without visible sclera, they were like
>   a golden rim around the eyes. She was covered with a soft, fur-like
>   plumage, white on her head and neck, where it was bushy enough to hide
>   away the fact, she indeed had a neck.
>
> Her vest only had a plate carrier in the front, even that had to be
>   enlarged to nearly twice the normal size to cover the chest that
>   housed the massive muscles, needed to fly. The back had a pair of
>   slits below the shoulders, where Iris' wings sprouted from. The wing
>   feathers were larger, more rigid and dark brown in coloration. The
>   arms were covered with brown feathers, abruptly ending around the
>   wrist. Thick, orange hide protected the hand. Ebony-black claws stuck
>   out at the end of each digit.

In short, I want to give everyone the "Mephistopheles Experience", aka: What I think I'm writing, the values, the morale of the story, the atmosphere, all that stuff.

According to the Reader-Response theory (and [Poe's Law](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PoesLaw)), different camps of people interpret literature differently. They have different needs and different buttons (you shouldn't push), and most importantly, different expectations, in terms of tone and so on.

I know it sounds misanthropic and dumb, but I'm afraid of the readers. What if they misinterpret things. For me every detail is important in establishing and reinforcing the atmosphere.

For instance, why mention the plate carrier? Well, because it lines up with the world that's established as realistic, these humanoid avians need large pectoral muscles to be able to fly, and they also have an extra set of limbs on their backs, so I adapted the armor to it by making it directional and a bit lighter.

Worldbuilding camp digs this stuff, but I'm unsure about others. **So, is it possible to write-as-intended and deliver my "experience" to others, or should I give up?**

Comment: Ow, that shade at romance readers. The stereotype lives on…

Comment: @Robin Then how did 50 shades happen?

Comment: @Mephistopheles The same way Independence Day did.

Comment: You would do well by cutting the "Star Wars" discussion as it's useless to the conversation.  You haven't once defined your "Mephistopheles Experience" and that's important.  Is it a villain that tries to corrupt the hero?  Is it something germane to your own writing?   And if so, what is your problem with your specific snippet of writing?  There are a number of issues I have, but those aren't going to be helpful to answering your question.

Comment: @hszmv What issues?

Comment: @Mephistopheles Surely it happened in a rigidly prototypical way that fully justifies the stereotype, with no nuance possible that would challenge it, especially when seen from a casual distance that requires no thoughtful scholarship or detail, nor ear for the readership, only seeing what one expects to see. Carry on with preconceptions safe and unbruised, please!

Comment: @Robin I mean, okay, I did generalize too much, but that doesn't make stuff like Columbine worshipers and similar, not desirable elements and their significance disappear.

Comment: @Mephistopheles:  Mostly grammar and structure.   Doesn't seem to be applicable to your own problem so I'll leave it alone.

Comment: @hszmv  Wha, no, I'm not that good at English, what are those grammatical problems?

Comment: I’m sorry, I lost the plot. Did you just  defend writing prejudiced words by calling romance readers worshipers of the Columbine shooters?

Comment: @Robin No, let me elaborate. There are deranged fan clubs that are larger and creepier than they should be. Columbiners were a bit of an extreme, but the trend is there. ["He looks sexy, so it's okay for him to drag me into a dungeon" and the "I can redeem him!"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BrqY9NiqHAI) Obviously most people aren't like that, but if that's the case, how could 50 Shades sell so well?

Comment: To your writing:  Why are you dumping a pile of uninteresting descriptions of your character into a place that doesn't need them?  "Humanoid avian" is descriptive enough, along with the beak.  I don't need these details, and they bring your story to a complete halt.  Three paragraphs in, and I still don't know why an avian who can't smirk feels the need to - but I have a **great** description of a figure I'll never, ever read about again.

Comment: @Mephistopheles That’s a whole heap of assumptions about a readership with a history of having prejudiced assumptions heaped on them. If you’re truly interested in the complexity of what women got from 50 Shades, there’s lots of scholarship you can find with ease, without hand-holding. But if you’re just repeating a *rhetorical* question to justify a thoughtless, throwaway example in the question, don’t bother hoping for my permission to remain uninformed. Either way, ball’s in your court now to educate yourself, or to not and continue to be thoughtlessly offensive in future.

Comment: I mean, really. You literally called romance readers garbage—not their views or habits, the people. If you can’t see how that’s offensive all itself before even the rest of what you wrote, it’s smart to cut my losses, right? No help for those who won’t even try.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, you are always going to go against someone's reader response.

Are you aware of 'The Death of the Author' by Barthes? Basically, your intention as a writer dies once the work is out there because it is completely up to reader interpretation (this is a simplification of the theory).

The only thing you can do is write it how you want to write it, and deliver the experience you envision on the page. You can't worry about reader-response because everyone will just interpret it as they want.

It's not something you can control, essentially because once the work is in another's hands, your authorial status dies.

Answer (score 1):

Take solace in the fact that most people will not read your story. If you manage to reach 10% of people, that would be a phenomenal success. For the other 90%, the reader response will be boredom and disinterest. I don't think there's ever been a story with universal appeal, and even the most successful ones probably don't get higher than 1%.

If you're lucky, your story will find its audience. Some people who will pick it up and keep reading. The trick is not to induce the correct reader response in everybody, but to help the story find those people that will have some response to it.

It sounds like it's one of those scifi stories that obsesses over realism and worldbuilding. If that's the case, then the worst thing you can do is dilute the mixture. We know there's an audience for those kinds of stories, and we know this is the sort of thing they like. Indulge as much as you can and assume that your readers are as smart about this stuff as you are.

In fact, it's probably better to assume that your readers are smarter than you. A little paranoia may spur you on to more research.

Answer (score 0):

You can deliver your experience to others, but just like your opinions, others will disagree. My stories occur in a world, and my hero characters express opinions about how the world should be. Many of those are my political opinions, too.

But, I should think it obvious, at least half the world disagrees with me, in some cases 95% disagree with me. I don't care, my heroes are **mine**, my imagination is **mine**, my fantasy worlds are **mine**, and my audience is entertained by that, or they are not. I'll let the market decide.

As it turns out, many people are entertained by my thinking and writing, so that's great. I am intentionally trying to entertain them and craft stories people will like.

Write what is in your imagination, with the intent of entertaining others. If you don't, you are doing something wrong in the writing, so learn to write to entertain others. Learn how to craft stories, and dialogue, and scenes, and descriptions.

I would only worry about how readers will respond to what you write in terms of whether enough of them find it entertaining that they will want to read it. If their response is "This is boring," and putting down the story, either get better, or write for just your own personal entertainment as a hobby, or stop writing and find a different hobby.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to avoid misinterpretation is by having little or nothing to interpret.

What this means is telling simple, realistic (not fantastical) stories. This is clearly not what you are interested in doing.

So, no, for the story you are writing avoiding misinterpretation is impossible.